# Grails - 404 File not found - but why?

Tags: grails, groovy, authentication

i start to write a simple login formular. This is the code for the view:

```
 <g:form controller="login" action="checkUsernameAndPassword">
        <input type = "text"name="userNameField" value="userName"/>
        <input type = "password"name="passWordField" value="passWord"/>
        <input type = "submit" name="loginButton" value="Login"/>

 </g:form>
```

this is the code for the controller:

```
class LoginController {

def index = {

    render(view: "login")
}//endMethod Index

def checkUsernameAndPassword = {

    [userName = params.userName ,passWord = params.passWord];

}//endMethod checkUsernameAndPassword
```

}

as you can see, it doesnt do anything yet, i just wanted to print the values on the screen, however i get a 404 message (i run the file on local host)

```
The requested resource (/projectName/hello/checkUsernameAndPassword) is not available.
```

I just cant figure out why. Would be great if any of you guys have a tip for me.

beste regards, 
Daniel

Edit (Change 1):

```
    def checkUsernameAndPassword = {

    render(view: "login",model: [userName: params.userName ,passWord: params.passWord])

}//endMethod checkUsernameAndPassword
```

}

(Change 2)
//added this line in view

```
<div>Username: ${userName} Passwort: ${passWord}</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<g:form controller="hello" action="checkUsernameAndPassword">
```

means that you have **HelloController** with **checkUsernameAndPassword** action

But in your code sample you have **LoginController** so to get your form work, you must write:

```
 <g:form controller="login" action="checkUsernameAndPassword">
        <input type = "text" name="userNameField" value="userName"/>
        <input type = "password" name="passWordField" value="passWord"/>
        <input type = "submit" name="loginButton" value="Login"/>

 </g:form>
```

**P.S.** In Grails world is sometimes much better to use GSP Tags instead of plain HTML because it will generate proper(in 99.99% of cases) HTML code for you.
So the best way to implement your form is:

```
 <g:form controller="login" action="checkUsernameAndPassword">
       <g:textField name="userNameField" value="userName" />
        <g:passwordField name="passWordField" value="passWord" />
        <g:submitButton name="loginButton" value="Login" />
 </g:form>
```

**P.S.2** Proper LoginController code(for the form described before)

```
class LoginController {

def index = {

    render(view: "login")
}//endMethod Index

def checkUsernameAndPassword = {

    [userName: params.userNameField ,passWord: params.passWordField];

}//endMethod checkUsernameAndPassword
```

Comment: oh sorry, i kinda wasted your time here, I tryed it as you said, i just changed it often and tryed any possible combination, i just copied a wrong one from the code, but strangely, after fixing it I get the following exception thrown: Exception Message: No such property: userName for class: iwinews.LoginController

Comment: rewrite [userName = params.userName ,passWord = params.passWord]; with [userName: params.userName ,passWord: params.passWord];

Comment: ok, that was silly of me, thanks you for that. The 404 message still occurs sadly. If somebody has any clues about that?

Comment: it's because you have no view associated with this action so your controller has nothing to display. Depending on what you want to be done after checking you could chain to other action or render view or just render any string

Comment: i got some example code and changed like shown in my post in "edit(change 1)", the 404 message is gone! thank you. But the view doesnt show the variables with this line: <div>Username: ${userName} Passwort: ${passWord}</div> somebody know why?

Comment: it's because you named your fields in view as "userNameField" and in controller you trying to get them as "params.userName". So to get your code work you have to change your starting view(just rename your input fields) or controller code( render(view: "login",model: [userName: params.userNameField ,passWord: params.passWordField]) )

Comment: @dan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1052/discussion-between-olexandr-and-dan)

Comment: i figured that out after searching. I really have to apologize! I posted to quickly, should veryfied my code before. Thanks a lot anyway.